# Deploying automatically Node app to App Engine with Cloud Build and VPC connector

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, vpc, google-cloud-build

i have a Problem during deploying an App Engine app with Cloud Build and VPC connector to my MongodDB Atlas Database.

When i deploy it with gcloud, it works perfectly with this command:
gcloud beta app deploy

**But i want CI (Continuous integration) to be implemented with Cloud Build.
During the Cloud build following error appears:**

```
Step #3: #============================================================#
Step #3: #= Uploading 2 files to Google Cloud Storage                =#
Step #3: #============================================================#
Step #3: File upload done.
Step #3: Updating service [nodeapi]...
Step #3: .......................................................................................................................................................................................failed.
Step #3: ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.deploy) Error Response: [7] Error attaching GCE network to app.
Step #3: 
Step #3: Details: [
Step #3:   [
Step #3:     {
Step #3:       "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
Step #3:       "resourceName": "projects/visifingc/global/networks/default",
Step #3:       "resourceType": "Network"
Step #3:     }
Step #3:   ]
Step #3: ]
Step #3: 
Finished Step #3
ERROR
ERROR: build step 3 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: exit status 1
```

**My app.yaml file:**

```
runtime: nodejs10
service: nodeapi
vpc_access_connector:
  name: "projects/visifingc/locations/europe-west1/connectors/app-engine"

network:
  name: default
```

**And cloudbuild.yaml:**

```
steps:
  - name: node:10.15.1
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ["install"]
  - name: node:10.15.1
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ["run", "build"]
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args: ["beta","app","deploy"]
```

When a I look in App Engine to the configuration of Instance which was deployed (but with the error, therefore not really deployed) 
**following App Engine Instance Configuration can be seen:**

```
runtime: nodejs10
env: standard
instance_class: F1
handlers:
  - url: .*
    script: auto
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
network: {}
```

As you can see, something is wrong with the network because it is empty.

Could you help me please to find a solution? I thought it could be a rights problems, therefore i tried to give to all the accounts access rights to VPC, but id didn't helped.
Mostly i am following the defined setup with VPC network which is described here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/connecting-vpc

Comment: I'm no expert of the nodejs environment, but as far as I know you can't have access to a VPC with a standard environment and I see the missing env: flexible field in the app.yaml - it's really strange how this works simply via gcloud though so I might be wrong.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same problem, and it turns out it *was* a permission issue after all.  For us, the fix was to give "Compute Network Admin" permissions to the CI/CD process.

Comment: This answer helped me. Just as a note, I made the permission "Compute Network User" (rather than "Admin") just to avoid over-permissioning

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue earlier and struggled with it for a while. Solved it be changing from "gcloud beta app deploy" to simply "gcloud app deploy." Don't know why the beta version isn't working (especially if it was working from your CLI).

I know this isn't a satisfying answer, but hopefully it puts you on the right track!

BEFORE:

```
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/google-containers/busybox"
    args: ["sed", "-i", "s/PROJECT_ID/${PROJECT_ID}/g", "app.yaml"]
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args: ["beta", "app", "deploy"]
```

AFTER:

```
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/google-containers/busybox"
    args: ["sed", "-i", "s/PROJECT_ID/${PROJECT_ID}/g", "app.yaml"]
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args: ["app", "deploy"]
```